# How can users prove a specific account has access to BigQuery? (AEAD encryption and authorized views)

Tags: encryption, google-bigquery, sql-view

I'm running an event where multiple people need to access BigQuery, and I want them to send me a proof that they have access:

- I want to collect email addresses of participants that can access BigQuery.
- I want proof that they have used BigQuery.

How can a user prove that their specific email account has access to BigQuery?

I'm wondering if we could build a solution with authorized views and encryption functions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We are going to use authorized views and the [new AEAD encryption function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead_encryption_functions)s.

First, let's create a key that only I can see in one of my private datasets:

```
CREATE TABLE `secrets.keys`
AS 
SELECT KEYS.NEW_KEYSET('AEAD_AES_GCM_256') key, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ts, 'for_a_view' label
```

Now I can create a view in a public dataset that leverages `SESSION_USER()` and `AEAD.ENCRYPT()`:

```
SELECT SESSION_USER() user, ts, key_ts, key_label
  , AEAD.ENCRYPT(key, FORMAT('%s|%t', SESSION_USER(), ts), '') enc_user_ts
  , AEAD.ENCRYPT(key, SESSION_USER(), '') enc_user
  , AEAD.ENCRYPT(key, CAST(ts AS STRING), '') enc_ts

FROM (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ts)
, (SELECT ts key_ts, key, label key_label FROM `fh-bigquery.secrets.keys`  WHERE label='for_a_view')
```

To keep my view public and the keys secret, I can set in my secrets dataset access to this new [authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views#granting_views_access_to_datasets) to read the key:

[image]

Now anyone can run the following query:

```
SELECT enc_user_ts
FROM `fh-bigquery.public_dump.encrypting_user_view`
```

Which returns:

```
AQElE+8cn+uHouGhZO7895UNjVs3/k05ZJLkEceQ8kszHJjQkbvuB6Vx/miDi3DhFTty7ZifXps1VKWC5OtTrQOkCQqoFFQu+VkDfz9F65R5f3PGPA==
```

I can ask users to share that value with me, and I can share that value with you - but only I can decrypt it using my secret key.

Decrypting with my secret key:

```
SELECT AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(key, FROM_BASE64('AQElE+8cn+uHouGhZO7895UNjVs3/k05ZJLkEceQ8kszHJjQkbvuB6Vx/miDi3DhFTty7ZifXps1VKWC5OtTrQOkCQqoFFQu+VkDfz9F65R5f3PGPA=='), '')
FROM (SELECT key FROM `fh-bigquery.secrets.keys` WHERE label='for_a_view' LIMIT 1)
```

Which returns:

```
⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛e@gmail.com|2019-05-14 03:51:15.047791+00
```

Note that's the exact account and timestamp they used to run their query!

And this is how - if I ever need proof that the account you are telling me you are using to use BigQuery is indeed that account, I'll ask you to run the following query and share its result with me:

```
SELECT enc_user_ts
FROM `fh-bigquery.public_dump.encrypting_user_view`
```

Comment: Related, how to use encryption functions for quick deletes: https://medium.com/@pdeyhim/bigquery-encryption-functions-part-i-data-deletion-retention-with-crypto-shredding-7085ecf6e53f

Comment: I'm getting a 403 for fh-bigquery:secrets.keys: "Access Denied: Table fh-bigquery:secrets.keys: User does not have permission to query table fh-bigquery:secrets.keys."

Comment: That's the point! You can get there encryption done, but not the keys thanks to authorized views.